# C# Linq with FirstorDefault

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

When I select a date I want to show the name of the users who made the reservation on that date, but I can only see the user who made the last reservation. How can I fix this?

Here my Code

```
foreach (Reservation i in con.Reservations)
        {
            var user = con.Users.Where(se => se.id == i.user_id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (i.date == date && i.hour == label4.Text )
                {

                label4.Text = user.Name + " " + user.Surname; 
                }
                else
                {
                    label4.Text = "17:00 - 18:00";
                }

                if (i.date == date && i.hour == label5.Text)
                {


                label5.Text = user.Name + " " + user.Surname; 
                }
                else
                {
                    label5.Text = "16:00 - 17:00";
                }

            if (i.date == date && i.hour == label6.Text)
            {

                label6.Text = user.Name + " " + user.Surname;
            }
            else
            {
                label6.Text = "18:00 - 19:00";
            }

            if (i.date == date && i.hour == label7.Text)
            {

                label7.Text = user.Name + " " + user.Surname;
            }
            else {
                label7.Text = "19:00 - 20:00";
            }  
}
```

here my table
[image]

My Form
[image]

Comment: FirstOrDefault explicitly asks for only one. Remove `.FirstOrDefault()`, then update your code to handle many rows instead of one.

Comment: When I removed .FirstOrDefault() , I got error.
I can't use like this -> user.Name

Comment: Yes, that's correct - part of the 'update your code to handle many rows instead of one' I mentioned. You now have a list of Users. Write your code to print out each user in the list. For example, you might want to separate names by comma: `var userNames = string.Join(", ", users.Select(u => u.Name + " " + u.Surname))`

Comment: I update my code like this `foreach (Reservation i in con.Reservations)
            {
                var user = con.Users.Where(se => se.id == i.user_id);
                var names = string.Join(",", user.Select(u => u.Name + " " + u.Surname));
                if (i.date == date && i.hour == label4.Text )
                    {
                        
                    label4.Text = names; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label4.Text = "17:00 - 18:00";
                    }
`

Comment: but nothing changes?

Comment: clear your code first. for example at least assign values to variables instead of textboxes. assign values to textboxes later after loop

also it would be helful if you post your reservation and user classes as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to do the following:

- Reset the labels with the default text
- Find the reservations for today
- Loop through those reservations and find the corresponding label for each hour (using the reservation hour you should always find one)
- Find the user (if any). If found, override the label text with the user name

Something like this:

```
var labelMap = new Dictionary<string, Label>
{
    { "16:00 - 17:00", label1 }, { "17:00 - 18:00", label2 }, { "18:00 - 19:00", label3 }, { "19:00 - 20:00", label4 },
    { "20:00 - 21:00", label5 }, { "21:00 - 22:00", label6 }, { "22:00 - 23:00", label7 }, { "23:00 - 24:00", label8 }
};

// IMPORTANT: Reset all labels text to start fresh
foreach (var timeLabelItem in labelMap)
{
    // labelXX.Text = "YY:00 - ZZ:00";
    timeLabelItem.Value.Text = timeLabelItem.Key;
}

var today = DateTime.Today;

// This would work even with DateTime.Now
// OFF-TOPIC WARNING: If you store UTC time, it will come back as DateTime.Kind == Unspecified. This can bite you
var reservationsForToday = con.Reservations
    .Where(x =>
        x.date.Year == today.Year
        && x.date.Month == today.Month
        && x.date.Day == today.Day)
    .ToList();

foreach (var reservation in reservationsForToday)
{
    // Get which label is affected
    var whichLabel = labelMap[reservation.hour];

    // Get who's the user, if any
    var user = con.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => reservation.user_id == u.id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // LabelXX.Text = "Juan D'Alotto";
    whichLabel.Text = string.Concat(user.Name, " ", user.Surname);
}
```

Comment: Did this approach work, and assuming it works... do you understand why it works?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your logic is wrong, I guess. You are assigning values for your textboxes and labels **INSIDE** a for each loop, that's why they always represent your last element in the Reservations collection when the loop finished. So you need to re-write your logic.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This way you will get all information you need about reservations on specific date (reservation_date)

```
 var reservations = con.Reservations.Where(i=> i.Date == reservation_date).Select(s=> new { 
      date = s.date,
      user_id = s.user_id,
      name = s.user.name, // Reservations should be joined with Users
      surname = s.user.surname,
      hour = i.hour
    }).Distinct();
```

Then you can apply rest of the logic

```
foreach (var res in reservations)
{
    if (i.date == date && i.hour == label4.Text )
    {    
        label4.Text = res.Name + " " + res.Surname; 
    }
    else
    {
        label4.Text = "17:00 - 18:00";
    }

    if (i.date == date && i.hour == label5.Text)
    {
        label5.Text = res.Name + " " + res.Surname; 
    }
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "16:00 - 17:00";
    }

    if (i.date == date && i.hour == label6.Text)
    {
        label6.Text = res.Name + " " + res.Surname;
    }
    else
    {
        label6.Text = "18:00 - 19:00";
    }

    if (i.date == date && i.hour == label7.Text)
    {
        label7.Text = res.Name + " " + res.Surname;
    }
    else {
        label7.Text = "19:00 - 20:00";
    }  
}
```